# Ошибка при компиляции в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Я не знаю имеет ли это связь, но я установил JavaFX последней версии[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также установлен последней версии jdk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красных элементов не видно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но компилятор выдает ошибку такого рода, говорит версия не такая у JavaFXsdk, вообще не понимаю че он хочет, если все новое стоит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что делать в таком случае?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй установить jdk версии 11, на офф. репозитории GitHub написано https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx14/doc-files/release-notes-14.md JavaFX 14 requires JDK 11 or later.

У меня связка JavaFX 14/11 + openJdk 11 проблем не возникает (javafx 11 + jdk 11 - отличная связка, детских багов при разработке точно не обнаружишь)